# How hide div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideDiv(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).Style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is element.style, not element.Style.  "style" is a CSSStyleDeclaration object, "Style" is undefined.  As such, for you, the code you need is:
`document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";`
Helpful reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";`

Comment: Lowercase "Style" to "style".  JS is case sensitive, Style is undefined.